# ArcGIS Pro: Calculate Field function to do multiple string calculations in one code block

Tags: arcgis-pro, field-calculator, python-parser, function

I need to strip leading and trailing whitespace, split string into list to remove excess whitespace between words and uppercase all values within one Python code block and calculation in Pro field calculator. I have the following code block started (below). I'm trying to identify the best way to account for all these stored variables before return of the final string value.

```
address =
fieldcalc(!address!)


def fieldcalc(address):
    str1 = address.upper()
    str2 = address.strip()
    str3 = address.split(" ")
    finalstr = ???
    return finalstr
```

Example bad string value: "    String  is    fixed  "
Final String Value: "STRING IS FIXED"

Comment: It is always good to give some examples so people can validate whether they understand your question correctly.

Comment: Why are you making all those extra variables and not using them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand the question completely, i.e., all edge cases depending on data, but the following should/might work in the expression box (no need for creating function):

```py
" ".join(s.upper() for s in !address!.split(" ") if s)
```

Comment: I don't see .strip() used here? And I need to use .upper(), not .title(), correct?

Comment: You don't need `str.strip` because the combination of splitting the string based on spaces and using a generator expression with a condition `if s` drops all the empty spaces.  And yes, you can change `s.title()` to `s.upper()`.  I will update the code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to remove excess white space is to use **strip/join** in combination with **str/or ''** for any fields that might have null (None) values.  For example:

```
' '.join((!Address_Number! + ' ' + str(!Road_Prefix_Dir! or '') + ' ' + !Road_Name! + ' ' + !Road_Type!.title() + ' ' + str(!Road_Post_Dir! or '') + ' ' + str(!Unit_Type!.title() or '') + ' ' + str(!Unit_Number! or '')).split())
```

This allows flexibility for each field, such as using the **title** function in the example above.  This is a good workaround to avoid the "None" error in the field calculator when using string functions with fields that may have null values instead of blanks.

Thanks and kudos to the link below for help with the **str/or ''** workaround.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-none-to-empty-string/